# Error from meson build for a missing header which exists

Tags: c++, meson-build

From this simple Meson build file I get an error on line *** about a missing header file:

```
# meson.build - src/

subdir('config')
subdir('testers')
subdir('utilities')

headers += [
]

mainPrj += [
    'entrypoint.cpp'
    ]

autoTest += [
    'entrypoint_test.cpp'
]

Source = [ headers, mainPrj ]
SourceTest = [ headers, autoTest ]

MyProgExe = executable('MyProg', Source)     ***
MyProgTestExe = executable('MyProgTest', SourceTest)

test('Internal test', MyProgTestExe)
```

This is the error message:

> src/meson.build:***:0: ERROR: File dataStructures.hpp does not exist.

The header does exist, it is in directory `src/config/`, and it does not appear in `src/meson.build` file, but in `src/config/meson.build`:

```
# meson.build - src/config/

headers += [
    'dataStructures.hpp',
    'interface.hpp'
]
```

If I swap `dataStructures.hpp` and `interface.hpp`, I get the error with `interface.hpp`.

I must be doing something wrong with the `meson.build` files, but I cannot find what.

Comment: why do you need headers in Sources? headers typically are not compilable files -> they are included into compilable files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to list your header files. Just add include directories like this:

```
inc_dir = include_directories('path/to/include')
```

in your case:

```
inc_dir = include_directories('src/config')
MyProgExe = executable('MyProg', Source, include_directories: inc_dir, ...)
```

What I usually do is to declare project dependency:

```
project_dep = declare_dependency(include_directories: inc_dir, sources: srcs,
dependencies[...])
```

and use that for each target (e.g. app and test executables) like this:

```
src_main = ...
executable('app', sources:srcs_main, dependencies:[project_dep])
...
test_main = ...
executable('unit_tests', sources:[test_main, test_specific_srcs], dependencies:[project_dep])
```

Answer (score 1):

If anybody has the same problem while building a `shared_library`, the answer Elvis gave also worked!
`inc_dir = include_directories('src/config')`

```
shared_library(
    ...,
    include_directories: inc_dir,
    ...,
)
```